# How to push int values into array come from all objects at once

Tags: c#, arrays

I created some objects from my Program class.I'd like to put all integer values that comes from objects and group them.To do that I created an array in class but when I try to add a new object I can't keep values on array because on each object creation,array changes.As I know I need static method to keep array when new object tries to reach.How can I keep string values when each different object from Program class wants to use any array?For example if int value of patient equals 10 ,name of that object should be on Group1.When its greater then 10 ,name of object,should be on Group2 array etc.This is a homework and as homework says I need to initialize element size of an array as 0.If I need more size I need to use Arrays.Resize() object to make it larger.When new data comes from constructor and needs to use array,I initialized temp value to make array larger enough.

```
        class Program
        {
            int temp=0;
            private String name;
            private int value;
            String[] Group1 = new String[0];
            String[] Group2 = new String[0];
            String[] Group3 = new String[0];
            String[] Group4 = new String[0];
            public Program(String name, int value)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.value = value;
if (getValue() <= 12 && getValue() >= 0)
            {
                temp++;
                Array.Resize(ref Group1, temp);
                for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++)
                {
                    Group1[i] = getName();
                }
            }
            }
            public String getName()
            {
                return name;
            }
            public void setName(String name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }
            public int getValue()
            {
                return value;
            }
            public void setValue(int value)
            {
                this.value = value;
            }    

            public String toString()
            {
                return "Name: " + getName() + " Value " + getValue();
            }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Program patient1 = new Program("Patient1", 10);
                Program patient2 = new Program("Patient2", 105);
                Program patient3 = new Program("Patient3", 321);
                Program patient4 = new Program("Patient4", 65);
                Program patient5 = new Program("Patient5", 98);
                Program patient6 = new Program("Patient6", 245);
                Program patient7 = new Program("Patient7", 8);
                Program patient8 = new Program("Patient8", 12);

                Console.ReadKey();

            }

    }
```

Comment: Your arrays are in the objects so each one of them will have their own arrays. I don’t think this is what you are asked to do but it’s difficult to understand exactly what you need to do

Comment: Side note, don't use get/set methods, use properties. There's already a virtual method on the object class called `ToString` (note the case), that you should override instead. C# has its own set of conventions, of course you're free to use your own but this reads like Java

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you need, either.  Can you post the actual assignment requirements?